# QGIS data attribute table reduced after export data from scratch layer

Tags: qgis, export

I have a situation like this:

[image]

namely, there is a plenty of items selected (roughly 14) with the willing of exporting them to the separate file.
When I export these selected layers to other file, they come as the one file. As you can see, the attribute table still shows 14 in total, but just 1 is populated under the "Select all items" options. It's exactly the same when toggle "Select items visible on the map".

Is there a bug, like I found here?

[https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12318#:~:text=Probably%20due%20to%20a%20cache,rendered%20on%20the%20current%20map](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/12318#:%7E:text=Probably%20due%20to%20a%20cache,rendered%20on%20the%20current%20map)).&text=Now%2C%20choose%20%22all%20features%22,have%20still%20the%20same%20list.

or is it my bad somewhere?

When exporting I use the following option:
"Replace all selected raw field values by displayed values"
but it doesn't help either

[image]

How can I prevent the temporary scratch attribute table from disappearing after the export?

Answer (score 1):

The problem applies just to the .geoJSON export.

It might be related to this issue:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/28580

For exports like Shapefile it works well, the same as for the .csv format.